# How do we use zero conditional and first conditional to talk about things in the past

Tags: conditionals

**Enter the reasons why I asked:**

From my understanding, zero conditional is used to talk about facts or habitual stuff, and the first conditional is used to talk about a specific event or case. (Source: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/first-conditional.html)

I am wondering how to use zero and first conditional when talking about things in the past. Do we just need to backshift the verbs and modal verbs?

I came up with some examples below.

---

**My examples**:

Example 1 - zero conditional in the past to talk about a general fact)

> When I was young, my parents were strict with me. **Unless** I received good scores in school, they **didn't** allow me to play video games.

Example 2 - first conditional in the past to talk about a specific event)

> I once played a truth-or-dare game with my friends and sister. My sister ended up sharing a lot of secrets with us. She wanted me to keep her secrets. **As long as** I kept her secrets, she **would** reward me by telling our parents that I did well in school.

Example 3 - first conditional in the past about to talk about a specific event)

> A Few years ago, I met a lovely girl at the beginning of school. **Unless** I talked to her, I **would** not have a chance to make friends with her. So I talked to her.

---

**My questions**:

Question 1:

> In my examples, I used "would" when it is first conditional and simple past when it is zero conditional. Are my examples correct? Do we just need to backshift the verbs and modal verbs?

Question 2:

> When using zero and first conditional in the past, do we also use zero conditional to talk about general or habitual stuff and first conditional to talk about a particular case?

Comment: I don't think you have understood "zero conditional". It's always present tense.

Comment: @Lambie "My sister wanted me to keep her secrets. As long as I kept her secrets, she would tell our parents that I did well in school. However, I didn't keep her secrets." Is this a first conditional in the past? Can I talk about a specific past event using first conditional like this?

Comment: The first conditional, as commonly taught to English learners, is simply the combination of the present tense in the _if clause_ (protasis) and the future with _will_ in the main clause (apodosis). It makes no sense to talk of the first conditional in the past.
Your third example, in fact, needs the "_third conditional_": _Unless I __had__ talked to her, I would not have __had__ a chance to make friends with her.

Comment: @Shoe Thanks for your reply. But I am not talking about the conditionals for unreal past. I wanted to use a real past conditional. I can see the confusion in my examples now. How about this: "At that time, in my view, unless I talked to her, I would not have a chance to make friends with her. So I mustered courage to talk to her." Is this correct first conditional?

Comment: @vincentlin. Your sentence is correct. But as I wrote above, the term "_first conditional_" generally refers to the _present tense/will_ clause pattern. What you have in your sentence appears to be the backshift associated with reported speech/thought. In other words backshifted from: _I thought, "Unless I talk to her, I will not have a chance to make friends with her"_ which does use the first conditional. It's up to you whether or not you want to designate it a "_past first conditional_" in the sentence you quote in your comment above.

Comment: @Shoe Thank you for your reply. You are very patient. I really appreciate that. So, can I say that my example (2) and (3) are just backshifted first conditionals? And when the context is clear, can I leave out phrases such as "in my view" or "I thought", just like what I did in my example (2) and (3)? I remember I have seen this kind of usage in articles, books, etc.

Comment: @vincentlin. In your examples 2 and 3 as they currently stand, it is not clear that these are backshifted conditionals. So the sentences will probably not be correctly interpreted without some indication that thoughts are being reported - e.g. by adding _in my view_. An exception is the stylistic device which is called "_free indirect speech_" and adopted by some novelists. You might be interested in researching this.