# How do we use zero conditional and first conditional to talk about things in the past

Tags: conditionals

**Important**:

I also posted this question on English Learner Stack Exchange and set a bounty. (Link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/288931/how-do-we-use-zero-conditional-and-first-conditional-to-talk-about-things-in-the)

But apparently, this question is too complex for the learner community, so I posted it here. If you are interested in getting a bounty, you can go there and help answer it.

---

**Enter the reasons why I asked:**

From my understanding, zero conditional is used to talk about facts or habitual stuff, and the first conditional is used to talk about a specific event or case. (Source: https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/first-conditional.html)

I am wondering how to use zero and first conditional when talking about things in the past. Do we just need to backshift the verbs and modal verbs?

I came up with some examples below.

---

**My examples**:

Example 1 - zero conditional in the past to talk about a general fact)

> When I was young, my parents were strict with me. **Unless** I received good scores in school, they **didn't** allow me to play video games.

Example 2 - first conditional in the past to talk about a specific event)

> I once played a truth-or-dare game with my friends and sister. My sister ended up sharing a lot of secrets with us. She wanted me to keep her secrets. **As long as** I kept her secrets, she **would** reward me by telling our parents that I did well in school.

Example 3 - first conditional in the past about to talk about a specific event)

> A Few years ago, I met a lovely girl at the beginning of school. **Unless** I talked to her, I **would** not have a chance to make friends with her. So I talked to her.

---

**My questions**:

Question 1:

> In my examples, I used "would" when it is first conditional and simple past when it is zero conditional. Are my examples correct? Do we just need to backshift the verbs and modal verbs?

Question 2:

> When using zero and first conditional in the past, do we also use zero conditional to talk about general or habitual stuff and first conditional to talk about a particular case?

Comment: Hi, vincentlin. You're using metalanguage that is considered too parochial on ELU, language ESL invented to lump conditional sentences into convenient categories, but really instituting far too loose an approach. Contributor/moderator tchrist has examined different conditional constructions, and is at the moment well beyond 250, if I remember correctly. // I'd just comment on (3) at the moment; 'A Few years ago, I met a lovely girl at the beginning of school. I realised that unless I talked to her, I would not have a chance to make friends with her. So I talked to her' sounds less incongruous.

Comment: 'Zero conditionals' hadn't been invented when I was at school. However, I think that to refer to the past your example 3 should be "If I had not talked to her, I would not have had the chance to make friends with her".  Your version "Unless I talked to her" seems more like a representation of your thoughts at the time.

Comment: I'm afraid the language of "zero conditional, first conditional" and the like belongs on ELL. It's also Not The Done Thing to cross-post, and **certainly** not to use a post on one site to advertise a post on another site. This question needs to be on the most suitable site.

Comment: About (2): 'As long as' refers to a duration rather than a single event; 'she would reward me by telling our parents that I did well in school' is iterative rather than durative, but still not semelfactive (single-event). 'Would' showing habitual practice works well. // In (1), I'd say 'wouldn't' and 'didn't' are both acceptable, but again the habitual (long-standing) practice (penalty enforcement possibly being iterative!) is well served by habitual 'would'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thanks for your answer to questions (1), (2), and (3). Your explanations involving iterative and durative are a little confusing for me. According to https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/first-conditional.html, the first conditional "describes a particular situation, whereas the zero conditional describes what happens in general." Does that apply if we talk about a particular past case and a past habitual thing? Sorry if I asked to many questions. If you have time, would you help answer my bounty question?

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Yeah, I think you kind of nailed the point that I wasn't aware of, because everything is kind of fixed (already happened) in the past. So I think my intended meaning is similar to what you said. If I add phrases such as "in my view" before my examples, will the examples make sense?

Comment: Notice that that article limits its definition of 'first conditional' and 'zero[th] conditional' (...) to sentences where the protasis begins with _if_, and restricted tenses/timeframe constructions (eg 'will get burned'). You're looking at different sentence-types. I'm afraid it's rather like asking 'How do I get the internet on my Kodak Brownie?' The four-type-fits-all model used in TEFL is just inadequate.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thank you for telling me that and that helped me organize my thoughts. Ok, do my examples make sense? I found those conditionals in my examples, like Kate Bunting said, are just like my own ideas in the past at that time because everything is fixed (already happened) in the past. Maybe I should add phrases such as "in my view" in the beginning? And second question, what type of structures should I look for to explain my examples?

Comment: I've commented on acceptability. Look up 'conditional/s' on ELU to find tchrist's list. I'm pretty sure they don't all 'have names'.  I'm pretty sure very few do.